# loop sum all selectbox value jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have a little question here...

lets say i have a 3 selectbox like this

```
<select id='attr1'>
<option value='1000' selected>Hijau</option>
<option value='2000'> Kuning </option>
</select>
<select id='attr2'>
<option value='2000' selected>Merah</option>
<option value='3000'> Biru </option>
</select>
<select id='attr3'>
<option value='4000' selected>Hitam</option>
<option value='5000'> Perak </option>
</select>
```

my question is.. how to use jquery to sum all of my selectbox value??
because my selectbox is dynamic.. so it can be more than 3 selectbox..

any suggestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sum =0;
$('select').each(function(){
    sum += Number($(this).val());
});

alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var sum = 0;
$('select').each(function() {
  sum += parseInt($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do that

```
var sum = 0;
$('select').​each(function(){
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
})
alert(sum)
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/jsG3N/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can usen the :selected filter,

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/XGca7/

```
$(function(){
  var sels = $(':selected');
  var sum = 0;
  sels.each(function(){sum+=parseInt($(this).val());});
  alert(sum);
});
```